# How long does my passport need to be valid after my return from the UK?

Tags: uk, passports

Next year I'm going to the UK. Shortly after that my passport expires. Is this a problem?  I know that for some countries, the passport has to be valid for at least 1 year more. How is it in the UK?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

source: [The Schengen Office](http://www.theschengenoffice.com/explained/passport_requirements.html)

Your passport must be valid for at least 6 months beyond the date of return from your trip. It cannot be damaged and any alterations/extensions must be endorsed by the Home Office or relevant Embassy.

Comment: it also depends on your nationality and point of origin. For EU citizens, I don't think there's any requirements except that it's valid for the duration of their stay for example.